# CSS: centering a tooltip for a button horizontally?

Tags: css, navigation, tooltip

I'm just not able to find a solution to this.
I have the following structure. This is just one of five menupoints - so normally there are five `<li>` items ins this ul.

```
<nav id="loggedInMenu">
    <ul role="navigation">
         <li>
            <a class="homeBtn" href="/my">
                <span class="homeBtnTooltip btn tt" title="Homepage">Homepage</span>
            </a>
         </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

As you can see withing my `<a>` I have a span.tt as a tooltip.
I made a live example of my code … check it out. http://jsfiddle.net/Ngjzk/1/

So normally the tootlip is hidden and is only shown when I hover over the green btn itself. However this is not the problem, this just works fine.

I simply have no clue how I can manage to align the tooltip itself centrally underneath the green btn.

So right now as you can see the blue tooltip is way to far right underneath the green btn. It should be aligned centally underneath the button.

I commented my little "hack" to do so out right now in the css section. Uncomment the last lines in the css to see what I'm aiming for.

However I don't want to have this weird hack and position each tooltip for each menupoint with a negative margin-left. Especially because the text for the tooltips is changed dynamically, so the tooltip should always have the full width of the text and be aligned centrally underneath each button.

Any idea how to so so?

Thank you

Comment: just a note, negative margin is not a weird hack, is valid css

Comment: I'd say you've got it fine as it is. That's not a hack, just a re-positioning. Leave it as is.

Comment: The problem with the valid-css-"hack" is when word length varies.. So -24px is fine to center "Homepage" what about if the label is "this is my page title and now it's not centered"?

Comment: did you tried with margin-left:-50% or someting like this http://jsfiddle.net/Ngjzk/4/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

edit [pushed correct answer to the top and history of this answer to the end]

Ok, you must use two-fold position; first (outer span, `position absolute; left: 50%`) and second (inner span, `position relative; left: -50%`)

http://jsfiddle.net/HerrSerker/Ngjzk/10/

---

*original*
Try a 'dynamic' percentual negative margin-left

```
#menu .tt {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 38px;
  margin-left: -50%;
}
```

---

*edit*
If you can rearrange your HTML, try the `span` outside of the `a`
http://jsfiddle.net/HerrSerker/Ngjzk/5/

Comment: That still doesn't center it :) I've changed the text in your demo to "Homepaeeeeeeeeege": http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/Ngjzk/7/

Comment: Thank you, perfect. Last question. Is it also possible to make a two word tooltip not break into another line? see this: http://jsfiddle.net/Ngjzk/13/ I want it to be a single line tooltip?

Comment: Found it … white-space:nowrap; makes it possible!

Answer (score 2):

YOu can do it with use of `:after` or put extra `span`

Check this

### http://jsfiddle.net/Ngjzk/11/

**UPDATED:**

### http://jsfiddle.net/Ngjzk/14/

Comment: @HerrSerker: I agree that the text should not be added with `:after`, but it is easy to change this to use the mentioned extra `span`: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/Ngjzk/12/

Comment: @HerrSerker; it's a demo example & also explain in my answer you can use extra span instead of :after.

Comment: @sandeep I agree with the span, but your text recommends the :after method so does your jsfiddle do. Edit your answer and I'll take back the -1